# What is the speed difference between using static class members instead of private fields?

Tags: c++

I am writing an application where I have static configuration class:

```
class Device {
public:
    static Device &getInstance() {
        static Device    instance; 
        return instance;
    }
private:
    Device() {
        init();
    }

    void init() {
        this->ramps_count = 300;
        this->gates = 64;
    }

public:
    Device ( Device const & ) = delete;
    void operator= ( Device const & ) = delete;

    int ramps_count;
    int gates;
};
```

This class is used to get and set my device configuration. Of course, there are other fields in this class. It is very important for me that it's static because I am using those fields in many places and it's convenient for me to use it this way. Also, I have functions to save and load this configuration to/from file.

On the other hand I have one class which is using this configuration very often. My application has a main loop where this class is invoked:

```
class FrameFFTProcessor : public FrameProcessor {
public:
    FrameFFTProcessor (){
    }

    void process ( ) {
        for(int i=0; i<Device::getInstance().ramps_count; i++){
            for(int i=0; i<Device::getInstance().gates; i++){
                //... doint it's job
                // and somethimes using values 
                // Device::getInstance().ramps_count and gates 
            }
        }
    }
private:
};
```

So I thought that it would be better to have those fields locally (inside my class) so that i wouldn't have to get it using static member, and I changed my implementation to:

```
class FrameFFTProcessor : public FrameProcessor {
public:
    FrameFFTProcessor (){
        this->ramps_count = Device::getInstance().ramps_count;
        this->gates = Device::getInstance().gates;
    }

    void process ( ) {
        for(int i=0; i<ramps_count; i++){
            for(int i=0; i<gates; i++){
               //... doint it's job
               // and somethimes using values 
               // Device::getInstance().ramps_count and gates 
            }
        }
    }
private:
    // private rewrite
    size_t ramps_count;
    size_t gates;
};
```

So my question is - is it better/quicker more efficient? Should I copy those values to private fields, or is it better (performance) to call static instance?

Keep in mind that I have more than 50 configuration fields, and they are used in 10 different processors (classes extending `FrameProcessor`).

Are there any better ways to do this?

Comment: The 2 are different, as the second is a snapshot of your singleton values (and those value can so be not synchronized).

Comment: What is the need for having a singleton for STATIC values. If your init is really using compile time constants, you should simply use static members or a single global instance of your class. If writing access methods give constexpr as hint to the compiler ( normally not needed if only trivial values are given back the optimizer will see this without it ). Having a singleton can result in a runtime check of existence of the object on each access. That costs time which is useless for your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the static configuration values as members of other class (other than the configuration class) is not recommended. The class (for e.g. `FrameProcessor`) should keep the data relevant to it, and not anything else. You may just get the reference/pointer of `Device` configuration class in `process` method, and use the data values.

```
void process ( ) 
{
const Device& devConfig = Device::getInstance();
        for(int i=0; i<devConfig.ramps_count; i++){
            for(int i=0; i<devConfig.gates; i++){
...
```

However, the `Device` class has issues:

- The data-members are exposed as public variables, and anyone can change it (may be inadvertently). You should provide accessor methods (const).
- The class is not thread safe. You either need to make it thread safe, or need to ensure that each thread has it own copy (this decision it totally on requirement).

You may write up methods for data access, and also make the methods thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

If your program is single-threaded, then first method appears to be faster since you don't spend time on copying the whole resource to your class object but just directly access to a variable. Compilers generally optimize the getter functions to let callers access the variable directly

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your cache usage.

If your accesses are all closely together in memory, the system can cache them. If they are scattered, it has to fetch from memory chips, which is the most expensive atomic operation that there is - we're talking about  a factor of ten slower than cache accesses.

By making fields static, you are putting them in a separate area of memory. But that might help or hinder your cache, depending on exactly how it decides to fill itself.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing a member of your class or a member of a singleton has almost the same level of indirection, you should aim to local variables to almost enforce the compiler to use registers.

I think a solution that can keep an optimal speed without having to store your *Device* internal values in your *Processor* object (that as other said is a **BAD** thing) is to... count backwards:

```
   void process() {
        int i = Device::getInstance().ramps_count;
        for(;i > 0; --i){
            int j = Device::getInstance().gatesl;
            for(; j > 0; --j){
                //... doint it's job
                // and somethimes using values 
                // Device::getInstance().ramps_count and gates 
            }
        }
    }
```

This is faster also because checking a value, presumibly inside a register for being different from zero it doesn't require memory access, while checking it to be different from a non constant value requires it (also a cache access is slower than no access at all).

I'm not inventing this one, most draw algorithms do this since ages.

Please also value to build const methods for your accessors, IE:

```
class Device {
[...]
public:
  int getGateSL() const { return gatesl; }
  int getRampCounts() const { return ramp_count; }
[...]
}
```

since compiler's optimizer can do more aggressive work on const methods.